# Laravel Eloquent model creation

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Can Laravel Eloquent models be created programmatically based on existing tables? It seems to be a substantial amount of work to create each one individually.

Comment: use artisan `php artisan make:model Foo`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isn't that hard when programming from scratch. But, anyway, if you want could create an [Artisan Command](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/artisan#writing-commands) and fetch all table names, to then execute the `make:model $modelName` in each.

so:

### 1. Create your command

```php
php artisan make:command GenerateModels
```

### 2. Edit your command

**App\Console\Commands\GenerateModels.php**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

// ...
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan;

    // some code

    protected $signature = 'generate:models';


    // some more code

    public function handle()
    {
        $tables = \DB::select('SHOW TABLES');
        $tables = array_map('current',$tables);

        collect($tables)->each(function ($model) {
            Artisan::call('make:model ' . Str::singular($model));
        });
    }
}
```

### 3. Run it

```php
php artisan generate:models
```

Comment: Thank you! It might have taken a significant amount of time for me to get to that point of understanding.

Comment: @ScottJohnson glad to help. Please, accept the answer.